# XCode: Running a build script in -x86_64 while building for arm64 on macOS

Tags: xcode, bash, macos, build, arm64

I am moving my app to arm64 on macOS12 Montery. While rebuilding its frameworks with arm64 worked fine so far i have some extend scripts in it that need to be compiled from JS to JSX before packing it to the app bundle. There's a Visual Studio Code plugin doing that for me (Extendscript debugger).

Therefore i have added a script phase with this script

```
node "$HOME/.vscode/extensions/adobe.extendscript-debug-1.1.2/public-scripts/exportToJSX.js" -f -n "$PROJECT_DIR/indesignagent/Javascript"
```

It works fine on -x86_64 but fails on arm64 because the plugin itself isn't optimized yet for arm64 and XCode seems to execute it with /bin/sh on arm64 arch

I found a manual solution i currently work with, but its just not as satisfying as an automated process:
I open the terminal with rosetta mode and call the above command and it works through, then i build my app without that script phase.

I'd like to know: Is there any way to execute a script phase/bash script with -x86_64.

I already tried solutions mentioned here in the script phase: https://medium.com/swlh/run-x86-terminal-apps-like-homebrew-on-your-new-m1-mac-73bdc9b0f343

```
arch -x86_64 /bin/zsh -c "$(node ~/.vscode/extensions/adobe.extendscript-debug-1.1.2/public-scripts/exportToJSX.js -f -n ~/workfolder/myapp-arm/indesignagent/Javascript)"
```

I think this won't work because XCode sets the interpreter in the UI here and i didn't find any way to prefix it with the architecture mentioned in the above linked solution
[image]

Any help appreciated

Comment: Couldn't you just execute node with `arch -x86_64` instead?

Comment: This is exactly what I already tried... won't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved it.
Node was installed with brew. Beginning with macOS Monterey  its installed in /opt/ folder which runs only on arch arm64. So i manually installed an older Version of node (< 14) in usr/local/bin which runs -x86_64. The last thing to do was to tell the script where to look for node and it works.
I can build an app for arm64 while in the build process calling x86_64 scripts (as long as they aren't updated for arm.